# Monitoring Packets in Android

Tags: android, android-networking

Let me explain what I'm trying to do to put more perspective. I want to write an app whose one of the function is to monitor network traffic. i.e. I want to able to read traffic generated by different applications. I want to determine if an application generates HTTP or HTTPS traffic. ie. whether an application is secure or not. Now, I have some code to run shell commands on the phone. I want to know what the best way is to achieve this task.

One idea I had was to use tcpdump and dump it to a file and then analyze it using some bash.But am not sure if tcpdump comes natively on android phones.

Thanks !

Comment: Fortunately, this will not be possible on-device without root privileges, for obvious privacy and security reasons. `tcpdump` does not ship with Android.

Comment: At one point I ran across a demo by one of the parental control companies (I think Net Nanny, but not certain). They achieved something similar (listening to all network traffic) by embedding their own custom module to the kernel of the system. If you are in control of the hardware that you want to run on maybe that is an option for you.

Comment: Well, I checked something out, and blindly ran tcpdump using a shell command, and Voila, tcpdump seems to be pre-installed on the android emulator. This means I can develop the functionality that I desire. I need to check if its natively installed on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Might also be worth taking a look at the ARO tool from AT&T. It analyzes network activity and is open source so there may be some code you can use in there too.
https://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=9700312